# HAML If defined? statement evaluating whether entry exists in Middleman data file

Tags: ruby, if-statement, haml, middleman, text-database

I have a [Middleman data file](https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/data-files/) `data/testimonials.yaml`:

```
tom:
  short: Tom short
  alt: Tom alt (this should be shown)
  name: Thomas

jeff:
  short: Jeff short
  alt: Jeff alt (this should be shown)
  name: Jeffrey

joel:
  short: Joel short (he doesn't have alt)
  name: Joel
```

It can have either default "short" text or an alternative text. For some testimonials, I want to use alternative text for some pages, while using "short" text for others.

In my `test.haml` I am trying to write HAML statement that checks whether alternative text exists. If it does, it should be inserted; if it doesn't, the standard text should be used instead.

Following example shows that `data.testimonials[person].alt` properly refers to information from data, because it can be inserted manually. However, when I use the same variable in `if defined?` statement, it never returns true.

```
Not-working 'if' way, because 'if defined?' never evaluates to true:
- ['tom','jeff','joel'].each do |person|
    %blockquote
        - if defined? data.testimonials[person].alt
            = data.testimonials[person].alt
        - else
            = data.testimonials[person].short

Manual way (code above should return exactly this):
- ['tom','jeff'].each do |person|
    %blockquote
        = data.testimonials[person].alt

- ['joel'].each do |person|
    %blockquote
        = data.testimonials[person].short
```

The result is this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is there any way to use a conditional statement that checks whether data exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defined?` does not really do what you want. You can just just leave it away, the `if` will just evaluate to `false` because the value will be `nil` for `alt`.

So just put

```
- ['tom','jeff','joel'].each do |person|
    %blockquote
        - if data.testimonials[person].alt
            = data.testimonials[person].alt
        - else
            = data.testimonials[person].short
```

Or you could actually write it much shorter:

```
- ['tom','jeff','joel'].each do |person|
    %blockquote
        = data.testimonials[person].alt || data.testimonials[person].short
```

I don't really know for sure, why `defined?` does not work, but generally you don't need the method to check for it, because undefined values will just give you a `nil` in middleman.

Comment: This works great and I love shorter version! Now I can introduce even more variations as this solution works with any number of OR statements.

Comment: @Rafal You are welcome  I just wish I understood, why exactly `defined?` is not working.

Comment: It is kind of good it doesn't work, as then I wouldn't know about this shorter version :) I thought I was missing something about how Ruby conditionals works, but apparently this is just a bug in Middleman.